# ReactJS - "Keys" error when adding components in loops

Tags: reactjs

I was following the tutorial on how to build with React with the TIC TAC TOE example, and I found it very interesting.

At the end of the tutorial, I found one of the following challenges:

> Rewrite Board to use two loops to make the squares instead of hard coding them.

This is the original `render`method

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(0)}
                {this.renderSquare(1)}
                {this.renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(3)}
                {this.renderSquare(4)}
                {this.renderSquare(5)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(6)}
                {this.renderSquare(7)}
                {this.renderSquare(8)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I first did it with just 1 loop and everything was working great

```
render() {
    let col_count = 3;
    let row_count = 3;

    let rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
        rows.push(
            <div key={i} className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(i*col_count + 0)}
                {this.renderSquare(i*col_count + 1)}
                {this.renderSquare(i*col_count + 2)}
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>{rows}</div>

    );
}
```

But then I tried to code it with 2 loops:

```
render() {
    let col_count = 3;
    let row_count = 3;

    let rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
        let cols = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < col_count; j++) {
            cols.push(this.renderSquare(i*col_count + j));
        }

        rows.push(
            <div key={i} className="board-row">{cols}</div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>{rows}</div>

    );
}
```

And I started getting the famous "keys" error on the console:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Board`.

So now I wonder: What is that I am missing? The rows have still a valid key ID that was working when i was just using one loop. And the columns inside each row come from another render method that has always worked.

Where is the problem with my second implementation?
How could I implement it so that I do not get that error?

**Update:**

In case needed, this is `renderSquare`

```
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
        <Square
            value={this.props.squares[i]}
            onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Try `cols.push(this.renderSquare(j, i*col_count + j));` and  `renderSquare(key, i) {
    return (
        <Square key={key}
            value={this.props.squares[i]}
            onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
        />
    );
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `<Square />` components need keys.

```
renderSquare(i) {
return (
    <Square
        key={i}
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this solved it! But why was it not giving a problem in the 1-level loop implementation, but in the 2-level implementation? I am not quite getting that...

Comment: The first implementation didn't have an iterator spitting out Squares. If you look at the error message, you will see it only pops up when there is an iterator. `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: oh wow... so it is not the same to do `<Square /><Square /><Square />` than doing `{arrayWithSquares}`? In the second case, I need keys? That is something I did not know... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I  believe you're seeing the **warning** because in your 2nd implementation you also have the **cols** array which is basically a list of **Square**'s. So your code is something like :

```
render() {
    let col_count = 3;
    let row_count = 3;

    let rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
        let cols = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < col_count; j++) {
            cols.push(this.renderSquare(i*col_count + j));
        }

        rows.push(
            <div key={i} className="board-row">
                <Square/> //needs key
                <Square/> //needs key
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>{rows}</div>

    );
}
```

Comment: Well, if keys were the items giving me problems, it would also cause a problem in the implementation with just 1 loop level, no?

Comment: In your first implementation you only have one array - **rows**.

Comment: so? What are the requirement so that "keys" are needed?

Comment: In rough terms, react needs a unique identifier for each array item in order to properly render and update them when state changes. As others have noted, you could send **key** as prop for the **Square** component.You can read more about Lists and Keys here : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sum** of iteration indexes like this:

```
  renderBoard(colsNum, rowsNum) {
    let boardSquaresArr = []
    for (let r = 0; r < rowsNum; r++) {
      let boardRowsArr = []
      for (let c = 0; c < colsNum; c++) {
        boardRowsArr.push(<span key={(r * colsNum) + c}>{this.renderSquare((r * colsNum) + c)}</span>);
      }
      boardSquaresArr.push(<div className="board-row" key={r}>{boardRowsArr}</div>);
    }
    return boardSquaresArr
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderBoard(3, 3)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and benefit will be function **renderBoard(colsNum, rowsNum)**(you choose size of your board)